# How to play audio music only once while rotation the screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I working on an Audio demo using with media player in Android. I need to play the song only once while I rotate my screen of the emulator.But when I implement this application and I rotate the screen pressing the button of Ctrl+F10 or Ctrl+F11 for landscape and portrait I'm facing the problem of my song is playing to start doubly again I start rotate song is start double and double again and again. Here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();
        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.issaq_tera_by_vishu);
        mp.setLooping(false);
        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);
        prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", true);
        prefsEdit.commit();
        mp.start();

        System.out.println("Media Plyer Is Start !!!");




        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Media Plyer Is Complete !!!");

                /*final SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
                prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", false);
                prefsEdit.commit();*/
                btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
                System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
                //mp.start();
            }
        });


        @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I have add the audio.xml file in layout-land folder in res directory

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display_Images"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_Audio"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPause_Resume"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/audio" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChapter"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chapter" >
            </Button>
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my AndroidMeniFest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.audio_demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.audio_demo.Audio_Activity"

            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout" Try with this attribute.

Comment: @SathishKumar That's quick, dirty and possibly the worst suggestion.

Comment: @MaciejGórski that code handles onConfigurationChnage so only i gave this

Comment: @SathishKumar I have use android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout" bit my screen only in Portrait mode.I want both landscape and portrait mode whenever i have change my screen orientation my song is playing only once.

Comment: @SathishKumar Read "Bad Practice: Retain the Activity" here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: @tazeenmulani : Use a `Service` to host the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: But i don't want to use service i want to start the song when i start my app it means in onCreate().

Comment: @tazeenmulani call to `onCreate` doesn't mean `when you start your app`. call to `onCreate` means the window to your application is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Managing `MediaPlayer` inside `Activity` context is not a good idea. Your `onCreate` is called every time configuration changes. It also leaks memory there.

For a quick, dirty, but not the worst solution, create `Application` subclass, move that code to a function there and call that function only once, e.g. from `Application.onCreate`.

If you want to control start from `Activity`, use:

```
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
app.methodStartingPlayback();
```

and make sure you guard the call inside `MyApp`:

```
private boolean playing = false;

public void methodStartingPlayback() {
    if (playing) {
        return;
    }
    playing = true;
    // ...
}
```

For a better solution, use `Service` to control the playback.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this code in my app i don't have an idea because I'm beginner in Android.Can you give me some example.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe MaciejGórski is saying, is to add a flag to check whether the music is playing before playing it. so you have a variable called "playing" and instantiate it to false. then in the place where you turn on sound, check if the flag is false, and if it is, turn on music AND turn on the flag. take the music control bit out and put in a method, as below (using MacieGorski's code as a foundation)

```
private boolean playing = false;

 public void methodStartingPlayback() 
 {
  if (!playing) 
   {
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.issaq_tera_by_vishu);
     mp.setLooping(false);
     btnChapter.setEnabled(false);
     prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", true);
     prefsEdit.commit();
     playing = true;
     mp.start();
  }
    //playing = true;
   // ...
 }
```

In the alternative, or maybe in addition, you should have the onDestroy method kill the music,  as below (credit goes to Lars Vorgel's tutorial, link to which I can't find now.)

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps